# Impact of log transformation and Normalisation in the context of EDA and ML

Tags: normalization, logarithmic

Is data normalisation an alternative for log transformation? I understand that both helps us to normalisation helps me to make my distribution gaussian.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok I just adjusted it